# How to extract various integers from a string in C?

Tags: c, integer, strtol

I was wondering how to extract various numbers from a string. I understand that strtol works, however it appears to only work for the first digit.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    long v1, v2, v3;
    char str[20] = "16,23";
    char *d;
   v1 = strtol(str, &d, 10);
   v2 = strtol(str, &d, 10);
   printf("string is %s\nv1 is:%i\nv2 is:%d\n",str , v1,v2);
   return 0;
}
```

In this example I would like to output v1 = 16 and v2 = 23.

Another example, if the str was "12,23,34", I would like v3= 34

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is all integers comma separated?

Comment: This is called ***tokenizing*** a string. If you search for `tokenize c` you'll get many useful results. Here is a related question here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Comment: Yes, the integers are comma seperated

Comment: change to `v2 = strtol(d+1, &d, 10);`

Comment: Then you can tokenize string using strtok_r function and then convert tokens to integers using strtol or atoi

Comment: That works thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

You can have many approaches. One of them is to make use of the `endptr`, populated by the previous `strtol()` call as the source of the next [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Otherwise, for a better and flexible approach, you also have an option of using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) with a predefined delimiter (the `,` here) to get the tokens one by one and convert them to `int` or `long` (as you wish) until `strtok()` returns NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `long strtol(const char * nptr, char ** endptr, int base)`.  The `endptr` allows for easy subsequent parsing as that is where parsing stopped.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int string_to_longs(const char *s) {
  #define N 3
  long v[N];
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    errno = 0;
    char *end;
    v[i] = strtol(s, &end, 10);

    if (errno) return -1; // overflow
    if (s == end) return -1; // no conversion
    printf("v[%d] = %ld\n", i, v[i]);
    if (*end == 0) break; // we are done
    if (*end != ',') return -1; // missing comma
    s = (const char *) (end + 1);
  }
  return i;
}

int main(void) {
  string_to_longs("16,23");
  string_to_longs("12,23,34");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtol` just converts a character array to a long int. It stops when it finds the first character that wouldn't make sense into interpreting an integer from.

There is a function in **string.h** named [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) which helps you tokenize a string.

Beware that `strtok` mutates the original character array contents.